# Get the list of test that are going to be executed with a PHPUNIT configuration file

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I've this simple question:

With the command

```
phpunit -c|--configuration <file>
```

It is possible specify a file which contains several phpunit configuration such as (but not limited to):

```
 <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="unit">
            <directory>path/to/directory/one</directory>
             <directory>path/to/directory/two</directory>
        </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
```

which will result in a list of tests to be executed.

While I'm not fully aware of phpunit internal implementation I'd like to retrieve in some way this 'list'.

Comment: I've added more informations.

Comment: Since PHPUnit 6.4 there should be an argument `--list-tests` (see https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1993). There are other interesting arguments, too (see https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/68ade3df2e7987ca6d2122cde5e7fd1d83e13a72/src/TextUI/CliArguments/Builder.php#L69-L72).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question:

If you look at the internal structure of PhpUnit the parser component is strongly coupled with the runner component invoked by the command.

This situation makes practically impossible to reuse the xml parser forcing you to either copy paste chunks of code or reimplement the parsing logic.

Long story short PhpUnit xml parsing logic is not reusable.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure phpunit.xml with your testsuites and run `phpunit --configuration path/to/phpunit.xml --testsuite <name test suite>`.

- If you run `phpunit` in even folder that phpunit.xml `--configuration
  path/to/phpunit.xml` is not necessary and you can run just `phpunit
  --testsuite <name test suite>`;
- If you want run all tests is run phpunit without `--testsuite <name
  testsuite>`; and
- If you want run just file, you can configure in your testsuite or
  `run phpunit path/to/Test.php`

Note: that phpunit find to files with sufix "*Test.php".

For more info, look at: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of all tests in order of execution by marking them all as skipped via a parent's setUp:

```php
public function setUp()
{
    $this->markTestSkipped($this->toString());
}
```